# Write multiple tests (it) in single .spec.ts file using Cypress

Tags: angular, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to write multiple tests (`it` blocks) in a single `spec.ts` file (Angular + NX project). My problem is that before executing the first test, the second test already starts executing, which prevents the first test from running.

In the example below, the 2nd `it` block the execution of the first:

```
import { login } from '../support/util';

/// <reference types="cypress-xpath" />

describe('merkur helper json-management functionality', () => {
  before(() => cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl')));

  it('logs in and goto json-management module', async () => {
    const uuid = () => Cypress._.random(0, 1e6)
    const id = uuid()
    const testFormName = `testname${id}`

    login('sadmin', '87654321');
    cy.wait(3000);
    cy.visit(`${Cypress.env('CYPRESS_BASE_URL')}/#/json-management`);
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.location('href').should('include', '/json-management');
    cy.wait(1000);    

  });

  it('should go into a distributor modules section', async () => {
    cy.log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')  

  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use async() on the it block.
This is the typical test with it block in cypress

```js
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Does not do much!', () => {
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })
})
```

You can read more details on the documentation

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test#Write-your-first-test